# Not able to perform left arrow and right arrow key operation in extjs grid textfiled column

Tags: extjs

```
var tmp= "<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr>";
tmp += "<td  height='35' align='left' valign='middle' ><input name='' id='' type='text'></td>";
tmp += "</tr></table>";
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":'KK', "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":tmp},
        {"name":'AB', "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":tmp},
        {"name":'FGF', "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":tmp},
        {"name":'dfsd', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":tmp}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1},
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

In the above code for phone no field i added html textbox. If i am pressing left/rigth keys in keyboard it is shifting to left cell or right cell instead of moving cursor in text filed. can any one give the solution for this one? I am using extjs 4.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

There are events on the grid catching the keypress.
Instead of trying to "insert" html code inside the value of the cell, why don't you just use the default "cellediting" plugin, as specified in the original example?

Just move the `editor` block from the email column to the phone column:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1},
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone',
            editor: {
                xtype:'textfield',
                allowBlank:false
            }
        }
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

This works for me, one you click once (or twice if you change the `clicksToEdit` from 1 to 2), you are now in edit mode (textfield by default) and you can then "navigate" your phone number by using key arrows.

With this solution, no need for the "tmp" variable (html code) you create, hence no event race.

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually my requirement is, In grid I need to have text boxes for columns dynamically(some rows may not have text boxes at all). That's why I am using HTML code for adding textboxes.

Comment: I see.  Maybe you could have a look at the componentcolumn by "Skirtle's Den": http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column.  With this plugin, you can have a "renderer" un your column that display a 'textfield' on every cell (of the given column).  You could even decide wether or not to display the textfield, if the value is empty...  Seems to match your requirements.